# DynamoDB PutItem does not create new item

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I use a lambda to detect if there is any `isActive` record in my table and `put_item` to update the id if there is.

For example, I have a placeholder record with ID 999999999, if my table query detected there's an active record (`isActive` = `True`), it will `put_item` with the real `session_id` and other data.

Table record:
[image]

My lambda has the following section (from my cloudwatch the `if...else` statement is working as intended to verify the logic). Please ignore indentation hiccups when i copy and paste, the code runs with no issue.

```
##keep "isActive = True" when there's already an active status started from other source, just updating the session_id to from 999999999 to real session_id

    else:
        count_1 = query["Items"][0]["count_1"] <<< from earlier part of code to retrieve from current count_1 value from the table.
        print(count_1) << get the right '13' value from the current table id = '999999999'
        table.put_item(
           Item={
                    'session_id': session_id,
                    'isActive': True,
                    'count_1': count_1,
                    'count_2': count_2
                },
                ConditionExpression='session_id = :session_id AND isActive = :isActive',
                ExpressionAttributeValues={
                    ':session_id': 999999999,
                    ':isActive': True
                }
                )
```

However my table is not getting new item nor the primary key `session_id` is updated. Table still stays as the image above.

I understand from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValueUpdate.html) that

> You cannot use UpdateItem to update any primary key attributes.
> Instead, you will need to delete the item, and then use PutItem to
> create a new item with new attributes.

but even if `put_item` is not able to update primary key, at least I am expecting a new item being created from my code when there isn't any error code thrown?

Does anybody know what is happening? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it with different specification for `ConditionExpression`. Did multiple troubleshooting ways and pinpoint the issue comes from `ConditionExpression`:

What i did instead -
add imports of `boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key & Attr`

and use `ConditionExpression` with `ConditionExpression=Attr("session_id").ne(999999999)`

and delete old id item

```
table.delete_item(
   Key={
       'session_id': 999999999
   }
)
```

Other conditions available here https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/customizations/dynamodb.html#ref-dynamodb-conditions

If anyone has any other better and easier way would like to learn